# AngularJS: on-click display some information between rows in html table?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an html table, `<tbody>` of it is generated with angular `ng-repeat`. Here is my `html`:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="car in carList | filter:tableFilter">
    <tr>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="{{car.carLink}}">{{car.name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{car.review}}</td>
        <td>{{car.rating}}</td>
        <td>{{car.fiveStarPercent}}</td>
        <td>{{car.recommended}}</td>
        <td>{{car.price}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is the part of my table in the browser:

[image]

With AngularJS, is it possible to do so, if you click on some table row, the rest of the table shifts a bit and in the middle some information about specific row is showing up? Here is an expected output:

[image]

**If it is possible then can I do this?**

Comment: You can always append a td with the styling that is displayed in the image after the click event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="car in carList | filter:tableFilter" ng-click="car.showDetails = !car.showDetails">
        <td><a target="_blank" href="{{car.carLink}}">{{car.name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{car.review}}</td>
        <td>{{car.rating}}</td>
        <td>{{car.fiveStarPercent}}</td>
        <td>{{car.recommended}}</td>
        <td>{{car.price}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="car.showDetails">
        Some details...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: There is one interesting issue, in your solution when you press on some row and then press on another, the first row doesn't close. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Instead of storing showDetails on the individual car objects you could store an `activeDetailsIndex` variable on your controller and just set it to the index of the car that you want to show.